# Choose different js file with same action

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a dropdown on my projects index page which makes ajax call to index action:

```
 def index
      @projects = sorted_projects # sort projects on basis of dropdown selection
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js { render 'populate_projects' }
    end
  end
```

and my populate_projects.js.haml file is:

```
:plain
  $("#sorted").html("#{escape_javascript render(partial: 'projects/projects_list')}");
  $("#normal").hide();
  $("#sorted").show();
```

this is working fine (ajax code is irrelevant). but now I want to add endless scrolling to same page . So first I added pagination to index action:

```
 def index
      @projects = sorted_projects
      @projects = @projects.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 9)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js { render 'populate_projects' }
    end
  end
```

I have my ajax part working but after the call I need to execute index.js.haml:

```
$('#normal').append("#{escape_javascript render(partial: 'projects/projects_list', :locals => {:projects => @projects})}");
- if @projects.next_page
  $('.pagination').replaceWith("#{escape_javascript will_paginate(@projects)}");
  $('.pagination').hide()
-else
  $('.pagination').remove();
```

So, now that problem is that how do I tell index action to render 'index.js.haml' when pagination is making the ajax call but when drop down makes the ajax all it should render 'populate.js.haml'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily add a parameter (e.g. `:tab`) to you AJAX call which tells what tab should be updated. To define whether you should append or replace HTML just check `params[:page]` wherever you want, in the controller:

```
format.js do
  if params[page]
    render 'populate_projects'
  else
    render 'index'
  end
end
```

...or in the view:

```
- if params[:page]
  $("#{params[:tab]}").append()
- else
  $("#{params[:tab]}").html()
```

*(the only one view!)*.

I thought at first, that you have have 2 paginations at one page, but it seems to be only filter + pagination.

But it's still unclear for me, why do you use `#sorted` and `#normal` divs and for what purposes you have created 2 js files, for name of tab, actually, is the only difference between `populate_projects.js` and `index.js`.

---

Let me suggest another approach.

Rails-way of rendering JavaScript is't the best to my mind, so I would write simple js for appending and replacing data, and separated if from index action.

At first, I would use only one div for rendering data (there still might be a lot of tabs, filters and so one). Then I would pass `layout: false` via ajax, and render index action without layout, then inserted result in div.

Then it would be for filter:

```
$.ajax
  url: 'projects.html'
  data:
    layout: true
  success: (data)->
    ('#container_with_projects').replaceWith(data)
```

And for pagination:

```
$.ajax
  url: 'projects.html'
  data:
    layout: false
  success: (data)->
    ('#container_with_projects').append(data)
```

Making these js procedures independent will allow you to use the same approach in different parts of your project, whereas creating useless `if` statements leads to unclear code.

Comment: thanks nirname. You are right having different '#normal' and '#sorted' isn't necessary.